# How to interpret HTTP Accept headers?

Tags: http, rest

According to the [HTTP1.1 spec](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.1), an Accept header of the following

```
Accept: text/plain; q=0.5, text/html, text/x-dvi; q=0.8, text/x-c
```

is interpreted to mean

```
text/html and text/x-c are the preferred media types, but if they do not 
exist, then send the text/x-dvi entity, and if that does not exist, send 
the text/plain entity
```

Let's change the header to:

```
Accept: text/html, text/x-c
```

What is returned if neither of this is accepted ? e.g. let's pretend that I only support application/json

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe you should respond with a **406 Not Acceptable**. That's how I read [this](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html).

Or a **415 Unsupported Media Type**?

I would opt for a 406, because in that case and according to the specs, a response SHOULD include a list of alternatives. Although is not clear to me how that list should look like.

Comment: 406 is correct in this case. 415 is for the case where a Client submits data (e.g. via POST) with a Content-Type the application can't handle.

Comment: Or you can send the requested entity in a format not specified in the request ACCEPT header, as noted in the specification for the [406 status code](https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html#sec10.4.7).

Answer (score 2):

"If an Accept header field is present, and if the server cannot send a response which is acceptable according to the combined Accept field value, then the server SHOULD send a 406 (not acceptable) response." -- [RFC2616, Section 14.1](http://greenbytes.de/tech/webdav/rfc2616.html#rfc.section.14.1.p.8)

Answer (score 1):

You have a choice. You can either reply with 406 and include an "entity" (e.g. HTML or text file) describing the available formats; OR if you are using HTTP 1.1, you can send the format you support even though it wasn't listed in the Accept header.

(see section 10.4.7 of [RFC 2616](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2616.txt))

> "Note: HTTP/1.1 servers are allowed
>   to return responses which are   not
>   acceptable according to the accept
>   headers sent in the   request. In some
>   cases, this may even be preferable to
>   sending a   406 response. User agents
>   are encouraged to inspect the headers
>   of   an incoming response to determine
>   if it is acceptable."